# Register worked before but doesn't work now?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, spring

OK, so I am trying to learn new things, so I created this project. I wrote the register function, and it worked just fine until I decided to add the delete function after that the deleted one worked, but the register doesn't work, and I get no errors on the console. this is my repository code

```
@Autowired
private DataSource ds;
public void add(User s) {
    try{
        Connection cn=ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("insert into users (username,password,birthdate) values (?,?,?);");
        ps.setString(1, s.getUsername());
        ps.setString(2, s.getPassword());
        ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(s.getBirthdate()));
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        cn.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public List<User> getAll(){
    List<User> list=new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        Connection cn=ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from users");
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            User s =new User();
            s.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            s.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
            s.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
            s.setBirthdate(rs.getDate("birthdate").toLocalDate());
            list.add(s);
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        cn.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
public void deleteById(Integer id) {
    try{
        Connection cn=ds.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("delete from users where id=?;");
       ps.setInt(1, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();
        cn.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is my rest controller

`

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userrepository;
@PostMapping
public void add(@RequestBody User s){
    userrepository.add(s);
}
@GetMapping
public List<User> getAll(){
    return userrepository.getAll();
}
@DeleteMapping(path="/{id}")
public void deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id){
    userrepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

`

```js
var userNameInput=document.getElementById('uname');
var passwordInput=document.getElementById('pwd');
var bdateInput=document.getElementById('bdate');


 

function onRegister(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
        var user={};
        var username=userNameInput.value;
        var password=passwordInput.value;
        var birthdate=bdateInput.value;

    
    user.username=username;
    user.password=password;
    user.birthdate=birthdate;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
     alert('hehehe');
        };
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8279/users", true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
    xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(user));

    

}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.11.5/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-8cU710tp3iH9RniUh6fq5zJsGnjLzOWLWdZqBMLtqaoZUA6AWIE34lwMB3ipUNiTBP5jEZKY95SfbNnQ8cCKvA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home">
              <img src="download.png" alt="Avatar Logo" style="width:40px;" class="rounded-pill"/> </a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav"> 
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="register.html">Sign Up</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Categories</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="trgames.html">User List</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Popular</a></li>
                      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Most Downloads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
        </nav>     
        <div  style="width:600px; margin-left : 50px;" class="container-fluid mt-3 float-start">
          <h1>Register Form</h1>
          <p>Try to fill the form.</p>
            
          <form  class="was-validated" onsubmit="onRegister(event)">
            <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
              <label for="uname" class="form-label">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" placeholder="Enter username" name="uname" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pswd" required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="bdate" class="form-label">Birth Date:</label>
              <input type="date" class="form-control" id="bdate" name="bdate"  required>
              <div class="valid-feedback">Valid.</div>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this field.</div>
            </div>
            

          <button id="butn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
          </form>

      

        <script src="js/register.js"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: you should debug via browser console

Comment: that was what i meant

Comment: i have done that

Comment: You should really enhance your debugging skills. You should at least be able to find out whether the bug is on server or client side. E.g. you can check out your old working version in parallel and step through both versions side by side. So you can easily find any differences.

Comment: i think it's on the rest side because i havent touched the js nor the html

Comment: Fine, and what hinders you to debug your server code?